# Delphi 2007 and Logitech Webcam Driver

Tags: delphi, driver, webcam, delphi-2007, logitech

A while ago I had this issue with Delphi 2007 unable to run and debug apps while the logitech webcam driver runs.

Apparently the Logitech Driver inserts a stub into every process running, thereby messing up the debugger's offset.

It's been a year and a bit - is this still an issue? Has Logitech cleaned up their act or do I have to dump my webcam for another brand?

Comment: It is one of the reasons I do all my development inside virtual machines; webcams and stuff are on the host, and the VMs are a controlled environment (which can be very 'uncontrolled' to reproduce specific cases)

Comment: I use VMs but just to test on a clean machine.

Comment: Yes. Logitech software sucks! They should hire a real programer for StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Olaf Monien](http://www.monien.net/blog/) the problem [still happening](http://www.monien.net/blog/index.php/2009/01/logitech-still-causing-access-violation-in-delphi-2009/) even in Delphi 2009

> Apparently even with the latest
>   Logitech drivers (11.1.0.2030 at the
>   time of writing this), this error is
>   still there (or maybe there again) and
>   affects Delphi 2009 too.

Logitech still [does not update the driver](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/435/243&hub=1&cl=us,en?osid=1), reported by Olaf.

[image]

More references

- [Delphi 2007 Update 1 and Logitech Camera Software](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nickhodges/2007/06/13/35998)
- [Delphi 2007 and QuickCam](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/delphi2007_quickcam.html)

Comment: Thanks. Wow it's really bad developing practice, injecting code into every other running process.

On Marco Canto it's reported that there's a host of other apps that are also killed because of this - including Alcohol 120%.

http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/delphi2007_quickcam.html

Well, to the bin with my webcam! Hello M$